# How to get a function to execute until the conditions are not sufficient

Tags: python, for-loop

```
import copy    
def remove_fully_correct(answer, guess):
        """(list,list) -> list 
        Return a list that removes the chars from the first list that are the same and in the same position in the second list
        >>>remove_fully_correct(['a','b','c','d'], ['d','b','a','d'])
        ['a','c']
        """
        res =  copy.copy(answer)
        for index in range(len(res)):
            for x, y in zip(res, guess):
                if res[index] == guess[index]:
                    res.remove(x)
                return res
```

Basically I have a function that removes all the characters from one list that are found in the second list, but my function only seems to remove the first value found from the list. Any help appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you may need a `while` loop.

Comment: Ya I thought so but I didn't where I should put the loop here: while x, y in zip(res, guess):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning inside the loop so you only have one pass through the outer loop :

```
import copy    
def remove_fully_correct(answer, guess):
        """(list,list) -> list 
        Return a list that removes the chars from the first list that are the same and in the same position in the second list
        >>>remove_fully_correct(['a','b','c','d'], ['d','b','a','d'])
        ['a','c']
        """
        res =  copy.copy(answer)
        for index in range(len(res)):
            for x, y in zip(res, guess):
                if res[index] == guess[index]:
                    res.remove(x)
        return res  # move outside
```

You should use enumerate if the lists are the same size:

```
def remove_fully_correct(answer, guess):
        """(list,list) -> list
        Return a list that removes the chars from the first list that are the same and in the same position in the second list
        >>>remove_fully_correct(['a','b','c','d'], ['d','b','a','d'])
        ['a','c']
        """
        return [ele for index,ele in enumerate(answer) if ele != guess[index]]


In [6]: remove_fully_correct(['a','b','c','d'], ['d','b','a','d'])
Out[6]: ['a', 'c']
```

using zip:

```
def remove_fully_correct(answer, guess):
        """(list,list) -> list
        Return a list that removes the chars from the first list that are the same and in the same position in the second list
        >>>remove_fully_correct(['a','b','c','d'], ['d','b','a','d'])
        ['a','c']
        """
        return [a for a,b in zip(answer,guess) if a != b]
```

Comment: It then says that index is out of range